# Flask-login not logging with Flask 2.3.2

Tags: flask, flask-login

Tested both on Python 3.8 and 3.11.2

I updated today from Flask 2.2.3 to 2.3.2 and login isn't working anymore.

I use Flask-login (0.6.2).
When, after

```
login_user(user)
```

the app makes a redirect to the user homepage, here the current_user is anonymous.

Comment: I had problems with this change even though we do not depend on authentication for subdomains, but because the app could not expire existing cookies and log users out after the Flask upgrade. To make sure that there was no disruption of user sessions, I had to also start specifying the cookie domain with the config setting to match the old value (i.e. add the period in front of the host).

Answer (score 2):

I've found out that the cause is that since Flask 2.3.0 SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN does not fall back to SERVER_NAME.

In previous Flask, if SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN was not set, then the cookie will be valid for all subdomains of SERVER_NAME.

Since in my application after authentication (in appdomain.com) the user is redirect to her homepage in her own subdomain (username.appdomain.com), then I had to set SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN so that the cookie would be valid for all subdomains of SERVER_NAME.

So I set this configuration:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = ".appdomain.com"
```

and it's working.